# Highcharts column graph colors via sql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, highcharts

I am trying to get the data that is being pulled from the bit.type to display as a certian color.

I got it where it pulls the names properly and display them under the series.

This may not display all the code as it is here is a proper link. [Full code](https://lilnetwork.com/download/code.txt)

```
<?php // Initialize require_once('../../../data.php');

function calculate_week_number($timestamp = 0, $start_of_week = 0) {
    // Use the current date and time if not set
    if(!$timestamp)
    {
        $timestamp = time();
    }

    // First calculate the first timestamp for the starting week of the year, using our nonstandard one
    $first_day_timestamp = 1 + ((7 + $start_of_week - strftime("%w", @mktime(0,0,0,1,1,date('Y', $timestamp)))) %7);
    $first_day_timestamp = @mktime(0,0,0,1, $first_day_timestamp, date('Y', $timestamp));

    $time_elapsed = $timestamp - $first_day_timestamp;
    $days_elapsed = $time_elapsed / 86400;
    $week_number = ceil($days_elapsed / 7);

    return $week_number; }

// Fill in the missing weeks in the week count function
fill_weeks($week_count, $mini, $maxi) {
    // Looping through the array and filling in the missing weeks
    for($i = $mini; $i <= $maxi; $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($week_count[$i]))
        {
            $week_count[$i] = 0;
        }
    }
    ksort($week_count);
    return $week_count; }

$sql = "SELECT bits.type,
               bitstatus.main_stop FROM bits JOIN bitstatus
    ON bits.serial = bitstatus.bs_serial WHERE bitstatus.status = 'Done' AND YEAR(bitstatus.main_stop) = '2015'"; //Create year changer

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$count = array(); $legend = array(); while($row =
mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $week = (calculate_week_number(strtotime($row['main_stop']) + (8 * 3600), 6) + 1);

    $count[$row['type']][$week] += 1;
    $legend[$week] = 0;

    if(!isset($min_week))
    {
        $min_week = $week;
    }
    else
    {
        if($week < $min_week)
        {
            $min_week = $week;
        }
    }

    if(!isset($max_week))
    {
        $max_week = $week;
    }
    else
    {
        if($week > $max_week)
        {
            $max_week = $week;
        }
    } } $legend = array_unique($legend); $legend = fill_weeks($legend, $min_week, $max_week); ?> <!DOCTYPE HTML> <html>     <head>      <meta
http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Bits Created per Week</title>

        <script type="text/javascript"
src="../../../../../../../jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css"> ${demo.css}         </style>        <script
type="text/javascript"> $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },          plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    colorByPoint: true
                }
            },
            colors: [
                    <?php 
                    $num_counts = count($count);
                    $on = 1;

                    foreach($count as $bit )
                    {

                        if($on != $num_counts)
                        {
                            if($bit == 'STEEL'){echo"'#FF9999'";}
                            else if($bit == 'STEEL CROWN'){echo"'#FF9999'";}
                            else if($bit == 'SLIM'){echo"'#9999FF'";}
                            else if($bit == 'KYMERA'){echo"'#FF2626'";}
                            else if($bit == 'HYBRID'){echo"'#FF2626'";}
                            else if($bit == 'EZC'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                            else if($bit == 'EZR'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                            else if($bit == 'EZB'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                            else if($bit == 'EZS'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                            else if($bit == 'RWD'){echo"'#FF9326'";}
                            echo ",\n";
                        }
                        $on++;
                    }
                    ?>

              ],
        title: {
            text: 'Bits Created by Type'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php echo implode(',', array_keys($legend)); ?>]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Bits Created'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{ <?php $num_counts = count($count); $on = 1; foreach($count as $bit => $bit_counts) {
    echo "            name: '$bit',\n";
    $bit_counts = fill_weeks($bit_counts, $min_week, $max_week);
    echo '            data: [' . implode(',', $bit_counts) . "]\n";
    if($on != $num_counts)
    {
        echo "        }, {\n";
    }
    $on++; } ?>
        }]
    }); });         </script>   </head>     <body> <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script> <script
src="js/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0
auto"></div>

    </body> </html>
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: Is there a question in all of this?  If you have a specific question regarding a problem you're encountering, describe it, and only include *relevant* code.

Comment: Yes there is a question in all of this.
The question is how to get the color to correspond with the names

Comment: the issue is under this section colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I had finally figured out how to make it work

```
        colors: [

                <?php
                    $num_counts = count($count);
                    $on = 1;
                    foreach($count as $bit => $bit_counts)
                    {
                        if($bit == 'STEEL'){echo"'#FF9999'";}
                        else if($bit == 'STEEL CROWN'){echo"'#FF9999'";}
                        else if($bit == 'SLIM'){echo"'#9999FF'";}
                        else if($bit == 'KYMERA'){echo"'#FF2626'";}
                        else if($bit == 'HYBRID'){echo"'#FF2626'";}
                        else if($bit == 'EZC'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                        else if($bit == 'EZR'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                        else if($bit == 'EZB'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                        else if($bit == 'EZS'){echo"'#FFFF26'";}
                        else if($bit == 'RWD'){echo"'#FF9326'";}

                        if($on != $num_counts)
                        {
                            echo ",\n";
                        }
                        $on++;
                    }
```

?>

```
          ],
```